# Where should I install the elgg social login plugin?

Tags: oauth, facebook-social-plugins, elgg

I wanted to know where I need to install the elgg social login plugin.  I have downloaded the latest 1.8 version of the plugin and unzipped it at the same level as the elgg index.php.  How do I use this plugin?  That is, what are the installation steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Elgg plugins go in the /mod directory. After putting it there, you will need to go to the plugin area of the admin page, and enable the plugin.